# Navigation fails, on clicking a button in Android Application, with error "Unfortunately, 'myapp' has stopped"

Tags: java, android, button, listener

Note: I've looked at other solutions and none helped me.

My application has a mainactivity that has a button to navigate to a second screen that has a button moving randomly. When the number of button clicks exceeds a count, it should navigate to a third screen. I'm able to click on the button in the second screen until the count just exceeds. But its not navigating to the third screen and I'm getting the stack trace error.

I'm posting my code below:

MainActivity -> FirstActivity -> Result

MainActivity.java:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);
    Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.firstActivity);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View arg0){
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FirstActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

FirstActivity.java:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);

    //Button - Random Placement on the screen
    showPopUp = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.showPopUp);
    absParams = (AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams) showPopUp.getLayoutParams();
    displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
    height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    r = new Random();
    absParams.x = r.nextInt(width - 50);
    absParams.y = r.nextInt(height - 50);
    showPopUp.setLayoutParams(absParams);

    //OnClickListener
    showPopUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (clickCount >= Count-1) {
                Intent result = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, ShowResult.class);
                startActivity(result);
            }
            else {
                clickCount = clickCount + 1;
                r = new Random();
                absParams.x = r.nextInt(width - 50);
                absParams.y = r.nextInt(height - 50);
                showPopUp.setLayoutParams(absParams);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And finally my Result.java:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);

    setResult(RESULT_OK);
    finish();
}
```

Below is the log:

> WindowManagerService.removeWindowInnerLocked:2744 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2640 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindow:2562
>   04-24 12:54:27.411    2934-2934/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.miotasolutions.t2t, PID: 2934
>       android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.miotasolutions.t2t/com.miotasolutions.t2t.util.ShowResult}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1761)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1485)
>               at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3736)
>               at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3697)
>               at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4007)
>               at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3975)
>               at com.miotasolutions.t2t.util.FirstActivity$1.onClick(FirstActivity.java:51)
>               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
>               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
>   04-24 12:54:32.037    1261-1328/system_process E/InputDispatcher﹕ channel '3a1187fd com.miotasolutions.t2t/com.miotasolutions.t2t.FullscreenActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!

And below is my AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<activity
    android:name=".FullscreenActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".util.FirstActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_first" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".util.ShowResult"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_result" >
</activity>
```

Comment: What exactly is the error ?

Comment: Did you initialize `clickCount` variable to 0? Also, did you initialize `Count` variable to some value?

Comment: It says "Unfortunately, T2T(myapp) has stopped." I'm sorry, if the error details are insufficient, but I'm building the app and running it on my mobile for testing. I do not have the required configuration to run the AVD and test the same.

Comment: @DeepikaRajani, yes I did that.

Comment: Post the Logcat error details

Comment: @Deepika Rajani, my next doubt would be how do I add the class to the Manifest file. Manually or there is a process?

Comment: `Intent result = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, ShowResult.class);` ShowResult is not added to the AndroidManifest.xml as an Activity. Add it to the manifest.

Comment: @LoveBeingNaive, you can add the Activity in Manifest file as .. `<activity android:name=".ShowResult">...</activity>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code for your Result activity, if you're calling `finish()` on the `onCreate` method, the activity will just close right after it's created, so nothing visible will happen.

Try commenting out the `finish()`, or put a breakpoint there to see it work.

Answer (score 0):

have you declared your activity in manifest? Because it is giving activity not found.

to add activity to manisfest file use
`<activity android:name=".YourActivity" />`

Comment: Pranav Agrawal, I did the same. But now, after clicking it just doesn't do anything. Since my if condition is passed, I keep clicking the button without any progress.

Comment: That is because when your showResult Activity is loaded first the layout is set as u have declared but after that it encounter `finish()` which closes the activity. Remove `finish()` that might help u.